# working with Image Slider using JS and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an Image slider and I just copied the code from a certain site. When I'm reviewing the CSS file, I came across a selector which is `.sliderInner` and I'm having trouble figuring out the meaning and function of it in `#slider div.sliderInner` for example and if it is a class name,id or class selector which is defined by the user; or a pseudo class which is predefined like for example :hover etc.

I have CSS file wherein `#slider div.sliderInner` is included/indicated and it is linked to an html file but in the html file, there's no `.sliderInner` class/id name defined and when I tried to remove the selector `#slider div.sliderInner` in the CSS file and opened the html file, the image slider which is contained in the `#slider` were lost.

This is the website I'm working on. 
This is the html file: 
view-source:http://arabiaue.x10.bz/activities/slider%202/demo8.html
This is the css file: http://arabiaue.x10.bz/activities/slider%202/js-image-slider.css

Comment: I don’t understand, what you are asking about ... Try to be more specific, and post only the piece of code you are having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a div with that class.

```
<div class="sliderInner"><div>
```

If you inspect the slider you can find it.

Its likely that some javascript is adding that class to that div and or creating the div with that class all together.

Comment: Thanks bro. You're right, I found it in the javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image Description screenshot]

If you see the above image you can see that a `div` with class `sliderInner` has been created and this will be done by the `slider` js file which you have included or plugin I can say!! It will hide your basic `html` added in page and create a layout to produce its functionality

Comment: Thank you sir @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)